# Make ASP.net Core 3.1 web app using a framework 4.7.2 class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-remoting, .net-4.7.2

I have a classlibrary that uses System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Http etc. 
Allready here you see red flags(remoting), but hey.. its what im given. 
Its the only way to communicate with the old legacy system (yes.. remoting), it works fine with .net Framework 4.7.2, does its job and what not. 
Though I need to make a simple to use api that I can run locally, dont ask why but I need to communicate with this legacy system, get data from it and expose it locally through a web API...

Though running a web api in a simple user friendly way IE. double click and run =>
As you can do with say, ASP.Net Core 3.1 applications, publishing it locally and I get this neat sexy little 80mb exe file that does everything for me (hosts the API, but fails to speak with the legacy software etc. because Remoting aint supported) Though I cant make it work with the Framework class library..

Any suggestions as to how i can make these two frameworks play ball? or is there a way to make it as easy to run locally as you can with this manner? I suppose I could somehow make the core application try to speak with something that runs/hosts the class library ( not sure whenever I use the right wording here) 
Im at a bit of a loss here.

Comment: .NET Remoting is not supported in .NET Core. .NET Remoting was identified as a problematic architecture. see [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/net-framework-tech-unavailable#remoting). You should migrate your legacy system to modern technologies. Or if you can't, use a .NET Framework as a bridge.

Comment: Yes, hence I mentioned the "red flag" of remoting. Changing the architecture of the legacy system is not an option as of the moment. You mention using .NET framework as a bridge, any suggestions as of how I can achieve this? 
|ASP.net Core|  |????|   |.net Framework with remoting|

Comment: Create a .NET Framework project (let's call it  Bridge), consume the legacy system via .NET Remoting, and expose a new service using Modern tech. Thus you can consume the new service with .NET Core.

Comment: Love it, I'll give it a shot :)